# module not found when setting angular controller test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-scope, jasmine-headless-webkit

I try to set up angular controller unit test following this [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02), the code is as follows:

```
describe('ProfileController', function() {
// load haloApp module
beforeEach(module('haloApp'));

it("should have notify_changed in scope", inject(function($controller) {
    var scope= {},
    ctrl = $controller('ProfileController', {$scope:scope});// inject controller
    // expect(ProfileController).not.toBeDefined();
    expect(scope.notify_changed).toBe(false);
}));
```

});

When I run this test case with jasmine, it report the following error:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

I have required angular file before this code snippet. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Are you including the angular-mocks.js?

Comment: Can you include the code of your controller, at least the declaration, not so much on the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `module` function is a part of the `ngMock` module defined in angular-mocks.js. Make sure that file is included when running your tests. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module